# Etymology of the term coherent in sheaf theory

Tags: soft-question

Why has been introducted the term coherent in sheaf theory? What's its intuitive significance? In italian we translate it with the term "coerente", in the sense of compactness.

Comment: I don't know Italian or French, but if coherente is also cognate to the French for compact, then this could correspond to the sense of compact as "topologically finite."

Comment: So, the fact that a coherent sheaf is a sheaf of $\mathfrak{O}-$modules of finite type implies, intuitively, the topologically finiteness?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44042/whats-coherent-about-coherent-sheaves